# Why do I get quota exceeded from Foursquare API even with a new token?

Tags: foursquare

I get a 429 quota exceeded response to the venues/venueid endpoint of the Foursquare API for every request. According to the docs, it should allow 500 authenticated requests per hour per token. There is no way this many requests are being made. I even created a new account, got a token that has never made a single API call, and it got quota exceeded on the first request. The headers have x-ratelimit-limit and x-ratelimit-remaining  both 0. What is going on?

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID?v=20180620&oauth_token=TOKEN